# PySpark filtering gives inconsistent behavior

Tags: pyspark

So I have a data set where I do some transformations and the last step is to filter out rows that have a 0 in a column called `frequency`. The code that does the filtering is super simple:

```
def filter_rows(self, name: str = None, frequency_col: str = 'frequency', threshold: int = 1):
    df = getattr(self, name)
    df = df.where(df[frequency_col] >= threshold)
    setattr(self, name, df)
    return self
```

The problem is a very strange behavior where if I put a rather high threshold like 10, it works fine, filtering out all the rows below 10. But if I make the threshold just 1, it does not remove the 0s! Here is an example of the former (`threshold=10`):

```
{"user":"XY1677KBTzDX7EXnf-XRAYW4ZB_vmiNvav7hL42BOhlcxZ8FQ","domain":"3a899ebbaa182778d87d","frequency":12}
{"user":"lhoAWb9U9SXqscEoQQo9JqtZo39nutq3NgrJjba38B10pDkI","domain":"3a899ebbaa182778d87d","frequency":9}
{"user":"aRXbwY0HcOoRT302M8PCnzOQx9bOhDG9Z_fSUq17qtLt6q6FI","domain":"33bd29288f507256d4b2","frequency":23}
{"user":"RhfrV_ngDpJex7LzEhtgmWk","domain":"390b4f317c40ac486d63","frequency":14}
{"user":"qZqqsNSNko1V9eYhJB3lPmPp0p5bKSq0","domain":"390b4f317c40ac486d63","frequency":11}
{"user":"gsmP6RG13azQRmQ-RxcN4MWGLxcx0Grs","domain":"f4765996305ccdfa9650","frequency":10}
{"user":"jpYTnYjVkZ0aVexb_L3ZqnM86W8fr082HwLliWWiqhnKY5A96zwWZKNxC","domain":"f4765996305ccdfa9650","frequency":15}
{"user":"Tlgyxk_rJF6uE8cLM2sArPRxiOOpnLwQo2s","domain":"f89838b928d5070c3bc3","frequency":17}
{"user":"qHu7fpnz2lrBGFltj98knzzbwWDfU","domain":"f89838b928d5070c3bc3","frequency":11}
{"user":"k0tU5QZjRkBwqkKvMIDWd565YYGHfg","domain":"f89838b928d5070c3bc3","frequency":17}
```

And now here is some of the data with `threshold=1`:

```
{"user":"KuhSEPFKACJdNyMBBD2i6ul0Nc_b72J4","domain":"d69cb6f62b885fec9b7d","frequency":0}
{"user":"EP1LomZ3qAMV3YtduC20","domain":"d69cb6f62b885fec9b7d","frequency":0}
{"user":"UxulBfshmCro-srE3Cs5znxO5tnVfc0_yFps","domain":"d69cb6f62b885fec9b7d","frequency":1}
{"user":"v2OX7UyvMVnWlDeDyYC8Opk-va_i8AwxZEsxbk","domain":"d69cb6f62b885fec9b7d","frequency":0}
{"user":"4hu1uE2ucAYZIrNLeOY2y9JMaArFZGRqjgKzlKenC5-GfxDJQQbLcXNSzj","domain":"68b588cedbc66945c442","frequency":0}
{"user":"5rFMWm_A-7N1E9T289iZ65TIR_JG_OnZpJ-g","domain":"68b588cedbc66945c442","frequency":1}
{"user":"RLqoxFMZ7Si3CTPN1AnI4hj6zpwMCJI","domain":"68b588cedbc66945c442","frequency":1}
{"user":"wolq9L0592MGRfV_M-FxJ5Wc8UUirjqjMdaMDrI","domain":"68b588cedbc66945c442","frequency":0}
{"user":"9spTLehI2w0fHcxyvaxIfo","domain":"68b588cedbc66945c442","frequency":1}
```

I should note that before this step I perform some other transformations, and I've noticed weird behaviors in Spark in the past sometimes doing very simple things like this after a join or a union can give very strange results where eventually the only solution is to write out the data and read it back in again and do the operation in a completely separate script. I hope there is a better solution than this!

Comment: In your first example it is also not working properly. Your second line contains `frequency:9` which should not be there. I dont understand why do you need to create an own function. Can't you just use the `filter()` function on the dataframe?

Comment: @gaw ```where``` is just an alias for ```filter```.